# Why is the last created Qt3DCore::QEntity always in the foreground of my scene view?

Tags: c++, qt3d, qt5.7

In my`Qt3D`scene, my 3D objects are not displayed according to their spatial positioning. The last created `QEntity` is always in the foreground, regardless how I rotate the camera. 
In my example, the `QEntity` `redBigSphere` is always in the foreground even though it is spatially positioned behind `smallGreenSphere` in the default view specified in the camera settings.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DRender>
#include <Qt3DExtras>

Qt3DCore::QEntity* createTestScene() {

  Qt3DCore::QEntity* root = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;
  Qt3DCore::QEntity* smallGreenSphere = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);
  Qt3DCore::QEntity* redBigSphere = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);

  Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh* bigMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh;
  bigMesh->setRadius(5);
  bigMesh->setRings(100);
  bigMesh->setSlices(20);

  Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh* smallMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh;
  smallMesh->setRadius(2);
  smallMesh->setRings(100);
  smallMesh->setSlices(20);

  Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial* redMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial;
  redMaterial->setSpecular(Qt::white);
  redMaterial->setShininess(10);
  redMaterial->setAmbient(Qt::red);

  Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial* greenMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial;
  greenMaterial->setSpecular(Qt::white);
  greenMaterial->setShininess(10);
  greenMaterial->setAmbient(Qt::green);

  Qt3DCore::QTransform* transform =  new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
  transform->setTranslation(QVector3D(0,0,10));

  redBigSphere->addComponent(redMaterial);
  redBigSphere->addComponent(bigMesh);

  smallGreenSphere->addComponent(greenMaterial);
  smallGreenSphere->addComponent(smallMesh);
  smallGreenSphere->addComponent(transform);

  return root;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;
  Qt3DCore::QEntity* scene = createTestScene();

  // camera
  Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
  camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45, 16./9., 0.1,1000.);
  camera->setPosition(QVector3D(30., 0, 60.));
  camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

  // manipulator
  Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController* manipulator = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(scene);
  manipulator->setLinearSpeed(50);
  manipulator->setLookSpeed(180);
  manipulator->setCamera(camera);

view.setRootEntity(scene);

view.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

(Image of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjyKB.jpg)

If I swap the order of instantiation,`smallGreenSphere` is always in the foreground.

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity* redBigSphere = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);
Qt3DCore::QEntity* smallGreenSphere = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);
```

(Image of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESGH6.jpg)

How can I obtain the correct 3D view regardless of the order of instantiation?

I am new to Qt and Qt3D so please consider this in your answers. 
(Due to my low reputation I can only provide the links to the images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question in greater detail in the Qt Forums and people could reproduce it there. 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/74419/a-weird-bug-why-is-there-no-spatial-depth-in-my-3d-scene/24

The problem seems to be connected specifically with `Qt5.7.0`. However, with `Qt5.7.1` it now works fine for me.